# Rails: Update only when checkbox is checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, updatemodel

I want to update a model - only lines where the checkox is clicked and insert a remark

View:

```
<%= form_tag update_fb_instruction_users_path, :method => :put do %>
<% @user_wishes.each do |u| %>
   <%= u.user.name %>
      <%= fields_for "instruction[]", u do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :remark_tl %>
   <% end %>
   <%= check_box_tag "instruction_user_ids[]", u.id %>

<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def update_fb

params[:instruction_user_ids].each do
@check = InstructionUser.update(params[:instruction].keys, params[:instruction].values).reject { |p| p.errors.empty? }
end
```

Comment: Thanks so far...  I have altered it with the same result..

Comment: Its is working now.. edited code above

Answer (score -1):

The issue there is that they all have the same name. So whatever value the last one is, that's what it will be in the request params.

It's a bit old, but you might want to check out the railscast here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1. The basic idea is to use fields_for on top of each user object. I haven't done it myself before, otherwise i'd write a full solution :).